# CROSS APPLY not working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, table-valued-parameters

I have a table-valued function I created to return values after performing a recursive query.  If I use a string as the parameter it works find. I use the same function in either a subquery or try to use the CROSS APPLY, I get a syntax error and it will not work.

Here is the code:

This returns values:

```
select
    meb.PART_ID,
    mec.[Matl $ ea]
from dbo.V_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Base meb
        cross apply dbo.FN_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Cost('4064T01G02') mec
where meb.PART_ID = '4064T01G02'
```

and

```
select
    meb.PART_ID,
    (select avg(mec.[Matl $ ea]) from dbo.FN_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Cost('4064T01G02') mec group by mec.PART_ID
from dbo.V_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Base meb
where meb.PART_ID = '4064T01G02'
```

This return the syntax error:

```
select
    meb.PART_ID,
    mec.[Matl $ ea]
from dbo.V_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Base meb
        cross apply dbo.FN_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Cost(meb.PART_ID) mec
where meb.PART_ID = '4064T01G02'
```

and

```
select
    meb.PART_ID,
    (select avg(mec.[Matl $ ea]) from dbo.FN_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Cost(meb.PART_ID) mec group by mec.PART_ID
from dbo.V_SEC_Margin_Expansion_Base meb
where meb.PART_ID = '4064T01G02'
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 99
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'

I've tried numerous things but no luck.

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM.  Is there a configuration change needed to get the CROSS APPLY to work?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: what compatibility mode is the database in?

Comment: *"I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM."* What do you have against patching?

Comment: In your last query, the outermost parenthesis is not closed. Not sure if it would give this error though.

Comment: It's (probably) worth noting that as well being an unpatched (and unsecure) version of SQL Server that you're using, it's also completely unsupported. I cannot stress that you **need** to look at your patching and upgrade policies here; they appear to be completely non-existent.

Comment: The compatibility mode is set to SQL Server 2000 which makes sense why it doesn't work.  Changed the compatibility mode and life is good.

Comment: As far as patching, I have nothing against patching.  Getting the business to allow downtime to patch is another.  I finally was able to use the security risk to get them to wake up.  We are in the process of moving from a physical server to a VM with the latest version of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies and the fix.  I should have thought of the compatibility mode.

Comment: There's a big difference between finding time to schedule downtime, and not patching (and therefore not restarting?) your server in over a decade. If you *are* getting off the unsupported version, that's great news. Just make sure you start patching that new server when you get it **regularly**.

Comment: That's the plan.  I inherited the current environment and working on getting things up to speed.